# Pandas read_csv with chunksize is skipping data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a data set that has 19090680 rows. That is over 19 million.  If I set the chunksize to 10 ** 6, my code runs twice. That is 2 million rows are processed before it terminates.  If I set the chunksize to 1000, I process 19087680 rows before I exit the for-loop.  That is still leaving exactly 3000 rows unprocessed.  Any idea why?

Here is my code.

```
cs = 1000
reader = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='|', header=None, iterator=True, chunksize=cs) 
chunkCount = 0
for chunk in reader:
    processedSeries = chunk.apply(process, axis=1)
    processedSeries.to_csv("processed_data.csv", index=False, sep='|', header=None, mode='a')
```

EDIT: I have pandas 0.17.1-np110py35_0
I am in the process of updating to see if this will fix the issue.

Comment: Why does your code terminate after processing only 2 million rows in the first case? Could it be that it terminates for the same reason (but much later) in the second case?

Comment: @IanS that is exactly my predicament. It seems to be exiting the reader prematurely under different conditions.  The two different chunksizes terminate the reader in two separate locations in the file so that is not a clear indication of any issue with the file I am processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Pandas 0.18.0 resolved this issue.